# Is there a way to specify page elements not to be translated with Google's webpage translator?

Tags: google-translate

I'm using Google's website translator and have a specific block of code which contains the names of schools. I don't want this block translated. Is there a way to tell Google to leave that block alone?

Answer (score 1):

Add `class="notranslate"` to the element.

Comment: you could be more specific